# Get ISOString in microseconds from unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, unix, epoch, systemd-journald

I have a epoch/unix timestamp which I have, which I get after running the `journalctl -o json-pretty -f` command. So I get my `"__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1576681153604871"` value from a given log. I want to convert this to an ISOString format, so I use the below code

```
var result;
time = parseInt(time);
var msec = time/1000; // convert __REALTIME_TIMESTAMP to milliseconds from microseconds
var myDate = new Date(msec);
var isoDate = myDate.toISOString();
```

I get the output as below

> "2019-12-18T14:25:49.605Z"

I wish to even display the microsecond part in this something like

> "2019-12-18T14:25:49.605762Z"

but `myDate.toISOString()` doesn't work properly if I don't convert the epoch to milliseconds.

I dont know if  `time % 1000` is the right way, to extract the microsecond part and then append it to get the desired output .

So is there a way to get the output in microsecond format ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So is there a way to get the output in microsecond format ?

Not using built–in methods. You can add the microsecond part yourself though. It's best to use string methods to get the digits to preserve leading zeros:

```js
// Time value in microseconds
let tv = 1576681153064071;
// Get millisecond part
let msec = tv/1000;
// Get microsecond part - keep leading zeros
let μsec = String(tv).slice(-3);
// Get ISO 8601 timestamp
let isoDate = new Date(msec).toISOString();
// Add in microseconds
let isoDatePlus = isoDate.replace('Z', μsec + 'Z');

console.log(isoDatePlus);
```

It might be better to replace the entire decimal part though, just in case some future implementation decides to add more digits after the decimal place.

```js
let tv = 1576681153064071;
let isoDate = new Date(tv/1e3).toISOString().replace(/\d+Z$/, String(tv).slice(-6) + 'Z');

console.log(isoDate);
```

Comment: good one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @RobG's example, the technically correct and faster code would be

```js
let tv = 1576681153064071;
let isoDate = new Date(tv/1e3).toISOString().slice(0, -4) + String(tv).slice(-6).padStart(6, '0') + 'Z';

console.log(isoDate);


// Less than 6 digits microseconds example
let smallTs = 50
console.log(new Date(smallTs/1e3).toISOString().slice(0, -4) + String(smallTs).slice(-6).padStart(6, '0') + 'Z');
```

RobG example cannot convert smaller than 6 Digits microseconds like `500` or `50` to ISO String correctly. Thank you for your answer though.